# C# Winforms Remove all references

Tags: c#, winforms, events

In the course of designing winforms apps, I will often double-click something on the form in design mode, which creates a lot of empty handlers.

```
    private void Tbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void Label14_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

I have tried just deleting them from the code, but if I do, the designer will freak out and delete everything from the form.  Is there an easy way to remove 40 or 50 of these stupid handlers in say, under 5 clicks?

Comment: No (but maybe there's an extension). Just don't double click the elements if you don't want the handler. You can go into the .designer.cs file and remove all the event subscriptions manually which is probably the fastest way.

Comment: "the designer will freak out and delete everything from the form". This shouldn't happen. I guess, it just says that it cannot build the designer mode, because you might have forgotten to remove the events from the .Designer.cs file.

Comment: When you create a handler by mistake, go back to the designer, in the properties window, select the events panel then right-click on the event handler you just created and select `Reset`. It will remove the newly create handler from code and designer files.

Comment: Ok, but after there are 10 - 40 of them that gets tedious.  I have found that I can click the "1 reference" link, find and remove the reference easily enough and then delete the empty handler.

Answer (score 1):

you just need to delete the event at the button with the thunder image, the event with "references" on the view code will become 0 and you can delete it without causing an error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jODI8.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There is a sophisticated way of doing this

1. Go to the form's designer window
2. Right-Click on the control associated with the event and click "Properties"
3. You'll come across this

[image]

4. Click the "Thunder shaped icon", Go to the associated event and Right-Click it, then finally click "Reset" the event handler has been removed successfully